# IntlDateFormatter parse doesn't work with specific params

Tags: php, intl

Something strange with data **1990-03-25** and **Asia/Nicosia**

```
IntlDateFormatter->parse
```

gives **false**

PHP 5.6.11-1+deb.sury.org~utopic+1
intl-3.0.0

```
<?php
$intlDateFormatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US',
    2,
    -1,
    'Asia/Nicosia',
    1,
    'yyyy-MM-dd'
);
$intlDateFormatter->setLenient(false);

$date = '1990-03-24';
$res = $intlDateFormatter->parse($date);
echo "$date - $res\n"; // 1990-03-24 - 638229600

$date = '1990-03-25';
$res = $intlDateFormatter->parse($date);
echo "$date - $res\n"; // 1990-03-25 - 

$date = '1990-03-26';
$res = $intlDateFormatter->parse($date);
echo "$date - $res\n"; // 1990-03-26 - 638398800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

So this has to do with the jump to DST. 25th March 1990 is when DST kicked in, so midnight on the 25th March is, in essence, non-existent. Nicosia changed to the EU rules on DST changes in 1998 (+1 hour at 3AM for DST, -1 hour at 4AM for going back to non-DST).

This means you'll either have to use '1990-03-25 01' for that date, or set the parser to non-strict to automagically overcome this issue.

OR, just use DateTime's parser rather than the Intl for simple numeric outputs.

---

*Original answer*

For some reason it seems to think that 1990-03-25 doesn't match the formatter you provided. Setting `$intlDateFormatter->setLenient(true);` allows it to parse that format. I do note you've set it to explicitly false at the top, mind.

Without lenient set, the error the formatter gives (checked with `getErrorCode` and `getErrorMessage`) is "Date parsing failed: U_PARSE_ERROR" - indicating that it doesn't think that the format matches the provided string. The second argument in `parse()` can be used to see which character it exited on when trying to parse the date. In this case it exits on the first character.

While this doesn't give you a solid answer as to *why* it thinks the pattern doesn't match, it at least gives you some basic direction on what might be the issue. I'd consider filing this as a bug to PHP, and see what the response is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I faced with this problem here

\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\DateTimeToLocalizedStringTransformer::getIntlDateFormatter

and changed form type